Create a player class in pygame and use in the main module of game
I have created a player class in a separate file to my main game that has the attributes x y speed colour size
I made a function called "render" that draws a rectangle using these attributes when given, inside of the player class file but I am struggling to then use this render function in my main file to render the square in as I get the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\leeun\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\NEA\mainmenu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from players import Player
  File "c:\Users\leeun\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\NEA\players.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mainmenu import screen
  File "c:\Users\leeun\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\NEA\mainmenu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from players import Player
ImportError: cannot import name 'Player' from partially initialized module 'players' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\leeun\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\NEA\players.py)

My main code is
import pygame
import button
from players import Player

pygame.init()

# screen size variables
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

# defining screen size/name
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Start Menu")

# game states
game_paused = False
menu_state = "main"

# text font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("arialblack", 40)
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("arialblack", 10)
font_header = pygame.font.SysFont("arialblack", 60)

# text colour
TEXT_COL = (255, 255, 255)
TEXT_COL2 = (0, 0, 0)

# loading / setting buttons
play_btn = pygame.image.load("NEA/images/button_play.png").convert_alpha()
quit_btn = pygame.image.load("NEA/images/button_quit.png").convert_alpha()
leaderboard_btn = pygame.image.load("NEA/images/button_leaderboard.png").convert_alpha()
back_btn = pygame.image.load("NEA/images/button_back.png").convert_alpha()

leaderboard_btn = button.Button(264, 300, leaderboard_btn, 1)
quit_btn = button.Button(304, 400, quit_btn, 1)
play_btn = button.Button(304, 200, play_btn, 1)
back_btn = button.Button(25, 25, back_btn, 1)



def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))

# runs the game
run = True
game_menu = True
player = Player(250, 250, 0.1, (0, 0, 255), 20)

while run:
    
    screen.fill((79, 101, 176))
    
    # main screen
    if game_menu == True:
        
        # check game state
        if menu_state == "main":

            # display the game name
            draw_text("Worlds Easiest Game", font_header, TEXT_COL, 50, 75)
            
            # draw main menu buttons
            if play_btn.draw(screen):
                game_menu = False
            if leaderboard_btn.draw(screen):
                menu_state = "leaderboard"
            if quit_btn.draw(screen):
                run = False
                
        # check if leaderboard is open
        if menu_state == "leaderboard":
            
            # display the leaderboard
            draw_text("Leaderboard display", font, TEXT_COL, 160, 250)
            
            # return back to main menu
            if back_btn.draw(screen):
                menu_state = "main"
    
    # the main game screen, this will include the player, level objects
    else:
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        draw_text("Press ESC to pause", font2, TEXT_COL2, 25, 25)
        # this is where i want to render the square 
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        
        # checks if ESC has been pressed to go to main menu
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                game_menu = True
                
        # quits the game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()    

and my player class is
import pygame
from mainmenu import screen

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, colour, size):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.colour = colour
        self.size = size
        
        
    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size))
        
    def up(self):
        self.y = self.y - self.speed
        
    def down(self):
        self.y = self.y + self.speed
        
    def left(self):
        self.x = self.x - self.speed
        
    def right(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.speed

I tried putting
player = Player(250, 250, 0.1, (0, 0, 255), 20)

before the main game loop starts and then using the render function at the place in my code where I put the comment but I just get the error as described.

Your code most likely returns this error because of a circular import. This means that while the compiler (Python) is compiling/running your first file, it tries to import a second file. However, the second file then tries to import the first file, which hasn't finished compiling.
The problem is with your mainmenu script using from players import Player and your player script using from mainmenu import screen.
To solve this, keep your from players import Player. However, instead of using from mainmenu import screen in your players file, just put screen as a parameter of Player.
Your player file should now look something like this:
import pygame

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, colour, size, screen):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.colour = colour
        self.size = size
        self.screen = screen #save the given screen as an attribute
        
        
    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size)) #use the given screen
        
    def up(self):
        self.y = self.y - self.speed
        
    def down(self):
        self.y = self.y + self.speed
        
    def left(self):
        self.x = self.x - self.speed
        
    def right(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.speed

Then when you call the Player class, remember to pass your screen as an argument:
player = Player(250, 250, 0.1, (0, 0, 255), 20, screen)

You are amazing bro, i'm not sure why i never thought about passing screen as its own parameter and was so fixated on importing it

@Caleb Don't worry, as you practice coding more you'll get better and better! ;)

I think your problem is a circular import. You are importing "screen" from your main class as well as player. But then inside your "player" class you are also importing "screen" from your "main" class, creating a circular dependency.
You need to remove the
from mainmenu import screen from your "player" class.
In general it is a good idea to separate game logic and drawing in separate classes/files. That way you are avoiding these circular dependecy problems.
